# Android Studio won't let me create an android project

Tags: android, android-studio

I can't create new android projects the way that it is intended to like [in the instructions](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/create-project).

This is the first page I get: [image].

I don't know how I create a android project from here. Also when I open older android project I can't build them...

I'm using Mac btw

Any Idea?

Comment: what is you IDE version?

Comment: Android Studio 3.2.1
Build #AI-181.5540.7.32.5056338, built on October 9, 2018
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1136-b06 x86_64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
macOS 10.14